# Missing records in Akeneo export

Tags: export-to-csv, akeneo

I'm trying to export products (csv) in Akeneo, but some records are missing in the output. 
The missing records are all part of certain *families* within Akeneo and I am trying to find out why they are not exported.

I have already `tail`'ed the log files, and checked the `log/batch/*` files, however, according to the logs everything seemed to be ok.

The only differences I can see (in the product table) are the family id's, but I must be missing something.

Any idea's/clues are welcome!

Comment: Using Version 3.2.45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't export products without any category.

Answer (score 0):

Categories were missing in the products, I guess these are obligated for a product to show up in the export.